# Outlook add-in office.js on appointment saved

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js

Is it possible in an office add-in (using `office-js`) to detect when the user creates an appointment in Outlook ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no straight forward way via Office-js.
Basically Outlook web addins are scoped to the item in preview, i.e, user invokes the add-in on a mail item (message / calendar event) and add-in can work with the item it was invoked on.

But if your addin has [ReadWriteMailbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/understanding-outlook-add-in-permissions#readwritemailbox-permission) permission, there is a roundabout way to acheive the same using REST

1. Get REST token using [Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.7/office.context.mailbox#getcallbacktokenasyncoptions-callback) API.
2. Using REST [push notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/notify-rest-operations) you can listen on event created.

Comment: How about  <Event Type="ItemSend" FunctionExecution="synchronous" but for calendar ?

Comment: It should work for meetings, not sure whether it works for Appointments(because we can only save appointment, there is no send option for appointments)

Comment: Just take a look at [limitation of ItemSend add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/outlook-on-send-addins#limitations) before taking that route.